# Android installer package database - as returned by getInstallerPackageName()

Tags: android, installation

I am posting this to create a database of well-known Android Installer Package name, as returned by getInstallerPackageName().

Following is my list, some are known, some are unknown. Can you please add OR edit where the information is missing or incorrect.

- com.android.vending - Google Play Store
- com.android.vending - Info needed
- com.google.android.packageinstaller - Google Update service
- com.amazon.venezia - Amazon Store
- com.sec.android.app.samsungapps - Samsung Store
- ir.mservices.market - myket store
- com.aptoide.partners.qmobile_store - Aptoide
- com.android.browser - Info needed
- com.google.android.apps.docs - Probably for apps installed from Drive Google
- com.lenovo.anyshare.gps - Info needed
- com.mobile.indiapp - Info needed
- com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer - Mi file manager
- org.telegram.messenger - Telegram
- pc - local install
- adb - adb install
- android.uid.shell:2000 - Info needed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

com.farsitel.bazar -> CafeBazar
com.huawei.appmarket -> AppGallery
null -> "Installed by Android Studio Build or installed by a market
app that has been uninstalled"